# Compute probability $P(U_1 \leq a\text{cos}(U_2))$

Tags: calculus, probability, change-of-variable

Consider the independent random variables $U_1 =U(0,c)$ $U_2=U(0,\pi/2)$

The challenge is to compute the probability:

$$P(U_1 \leq a\text{cos}(U_2))$$

An attempt:

$$P(U_1 \leq a\text{cos}(U_2))=P(U_1-acos(U_2)\leq0)$$

Applying convolution:
$$\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{U_1}(t)f_{-a\text{cos}(U_2)}(x-t)dtdx$$
By independence:
$$=\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{U_1,-a\text{cos}(U_2)}(t,x-t)dtdx$$

This is where I get stuck, I believe using multivariate change of variable does the trick. The transform should give:

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a \text{cos(t)}} f_{U_1,U_2}(x,t)dxdt$$

From which it's no trouble to carry out the computation to the end. Is it correct to use multivariable change of variable in the above, and if so, what transformation should be performed?

Comment: \begin{align}
P(U_1\le a\cos U_2)&=\frac{2}{\pi c}\iint_{x\le a\cos y}\mathbf1_{0<x<c,0<y<\pi/2}\,dx\,dy
\\&=\frac{2}{\pi c}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\min(c,a\cos y)}\,dx\,dy
\end{align}

Comment: You can just start **directly** with:$$P(U_1\leq a\cos U_2)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_{U_1\leq a\cos U_2}=\int\int\mathbf1_{u\leq a\cos v}f_{U,V}(u,v)dudv$$ leading to the expression mentioned by @StubbornAtom. No change of variables (or other tricks) is required.

Comment: @drhab I can see that the method is quite favorable. But CAN this be solved using the transform?

Comment: Why do you think that $P(U_1-a\cos U_2\leq0)=P(U_1+a\cos U_2\leq0)$?

Comment: @drhab Good catch, corrected!

Comment: @drhab Still wondering about this question. Is there a proof for the formula you presented? It seems like it could be proven by change of variable argument, which would answer the question.

Comment: "...the formula you presented". What do you mean by that? I presented the equalities $P(U_1\leq a\cos U_2)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_{U_1\leq a\cos U_2}=\int\int\mathbf1_{u\leq a\cos v}f_{U,V}(u,v)dudv$. Do you want a proof for (one of) these equalities?

Comment: @drhab Yes, the RH side equality in particular. Maybe I am missing something obvious....

Comment: In general if $U_1,U_2$ have a joint distribution with PDF $f$ then $\mathbb Eg(U_1,U_2)=\int\int g(u,v)f(u,v)dudv$. That is where the RHS comes from. This for $g(u,v)=\mathbf1_{u\leq a\cos v}$. I accidently wrote $f_{U,V}$ for the PDF but should have written $f_{U_1,U_2}$.